# Data filter from database with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to filter a specific set of data from DB with SQL according to its release date, yeah I am developing a movie site. I want to get those data which gonna come in future at the top with ASC order then the past data, I mean released data with DESC order and I got that with the help of StackOverflow community. But It feels like I am having another problem that, I want that, the data which passed its released date, its gonna stay top for first 15 days then follow my rule which I said at the first.

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `imdbID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `poster` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `year` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rel_date` date NOT NULL,
  `main_menu_id` int(255) NOT NULL
)

--
ALTER TABLE `movies`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `movies`
  MODIFY `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=131;
COMMIT;
```

I have been using this to keep upcoming data at the top with ASC order then released data with DESC order by rel_date

```
SELECT t.* FROM movies t 
where main_menu_id=".$menu_id." 
ORDER BY 
DATE(t.rel_date) >= DATE(NOW()) DESC , 
IF(DATE(t.rel_date)<DATE(NOW()),t.rel_date,DATE(NULL)) DESC ,
 t.rel_date ASC
```

Now I expect the data which released stays at the top for the first 15 days then follow my recent code.
I know It was a horrible description coz it's my first post. Sorry about that.

Comment: Does MySQL have a date add function you can use to achieve this?

Comment: Yeah it does but its doesnt give me the result what i want, I want released data should be placed at the top in first 15 days.

Comment: You may find it easiest to build a calculated column and sort by that. Use a subquery if necessary.

Comment: I am not good at sub query, can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

I created this code in Postgresql, but you need converte function now() to mysql.

```
create table test ( id serial, release date );

insert into test (release) values ( to_date('01/04/2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') );
insert into test (release) values ( to_date('02/04/2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') );
insert into test (release) values ( to_date('03/04/2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') );

insert into test (release) values ( to_date('15/04/2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') );
insert into test (release) values ( to_date('16/04/2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') );
insert into test (release) values ( to_date('17/04/2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') );


select
    release
from (
(
select
    0 priority,
    release
from test
where
    release >= (now() - INTERVAL '15 DAY')::date
)
union
(
select
    1 priority,
    release
from test
where
    release < (now() - INTERVAL '15 DAY')::date
)) foo
order by
    priority;
```